# When Long touch on my website image from mobile device come design issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website using desktop to mouse enter and mouse leave on image is working fine,
but when I am using mobile device and tablet a design issue occurs. When I use this web on touch device long press on image it shows design issue.

This is my web site link please check on your mobile or tablet.

[easyinnolight.com](http://www.easyinnolight.com)

Comment: What is your problem exactly, should we imagine what's the issue here?

Comment: when long press on box image. hove elements are disaligned

Comment: when long press on box image. hove elements are disaligned

Comment: if you don't mine give your number i will call you. its very urgent delivery to client. could you please help me

Comment: @Chandrasekaran M i see that in console.log their are error regarding `404 file not found `

Comment: @PavanBaddi i have no problem in desktop. i have problem in mobile device only

Comment: add `position: absolute;` to  `#featurecontent` in mobile

Comment: also do not use multiple same ID, Use class instead this is not good practice to use multiple ID like u did for #featurecontent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `position: absolute;` to `#featurecontent` seems fix your issue